# Crispy_forms_tags not fill form with instance in my update view

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

My problem about Update View
On my UpdateView when I use {{form.as_p}} , Its work. But when I use {% load crispy_forms_tags %} Form not fill with instance.

My View.py;

```
def ayarlar (request):
    userinstance=get_object_or_404(kullaniciBilgileri,id=1)
    form =  KullaniciForm(request.POST or None, instance=userinstance)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    context={
         'form':form,
    }
    return render(request, 'cek/ayar.html',context)
```

In my template {{forms.as_p}} is working but I wanna this type:

```
<form action="" method="post">
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
    {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-row" >


    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label>First Name</label>
      <input type="text" name='{{ form.firstName.name }}' class="form-control"  >
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label>Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" name='{{ form.lastName.name }}' class="form-control"  >
    </div>


  </div>
```

But this type dont fill with instance.

How can I solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

**{% load crispy_forms_tags %}** this should be above form tag.

**Template**

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
  </form>
```

---

With Custom Fields:

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}  #< should be above form tag

<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-row" >
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label>First Name</label>
      <input type="text" name='{{ form.firstName.name|as_crispy_field }}' class="form-control"  >
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label>Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" name='{{ form.lastName.name|as_crispy_field }}' class="form-control"  >
    </div>


  </div>
```